# R sample into two lists

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I want to sample from a list of 97 values. The list is composed of 3 different values (1,2 and 3), each representing a certain condition. The 97 values represent 97 individuals. 
Lets assume the list is called `original_pop`. I want to randomly choose 50 individuals and store them as males and take the remaining 47 individuals and store them as females. A simple and similar scenario:

```
original_pop = [1 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 3 1 ...]
male_pop = [50 random values from original_pop]
female_pop = [the 47 values that are not in male_pop]
```

I created `original_pop` with sample so that the values are random but I don't know how to do the rest. Right now I've stored the first 50 values of `original_pop` as males and the last 47 as females and it might work because `original_pop` was randomly generated but I think it would be more appropriate to choose the values from `original_pop` in a random way and not in order.

Appreciate your responses!

Comment: `samps <- sample(97, 50); males <- original[samps]; females <- original[-samps]`

Comment: @bouncyball Thx a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n <- 97
```

In the absence of your `original_pop` data, we simulate it below.

```
original_pop <- sample(1:3, size=n, replace=TRUE)
maleIndexes <- sample(n, 50)
males <- original_pop[maleIndexes]
females <- original_pop[-maleIndexes]
```